# git recover branch deleted on remote and local folder deleted

Tags: git, branch

I have lost some work and Im trying to recover it. Basically I created a branch locally, commited, pushed, and then did some clean up and deleted the branch locally, remotely and the directory containing the project locally (I thought I could always clone it anytime later). I don't know why I forgot to merge with "dev".

I checked my bash history to see what could have happened, and I think I could figure out what commands were executed (see below).

I have been looking around for answers about this, found tons of them but none worked (even the promising fsck/reflog)

basically this is what seem to have happened (2 weeks ago) :

```
git clone ssh://.../myproject
cd myproject
git checkout dev
vim hello
git commit -m "new commit"
git push origin dev

git checkout -b newbranch
vim blabla
git add blabla
git commit -m "new commit"
git push
git checkout dev
git push origin --delete newbranch
git branch -d newbranch
cd ..
rm -rf myproject
```

English is not my native language, I can clarify any point/edit my question if needed. Thanks in advance for helping me find a solution other than jumping out of the window

Comment: Did you run `fsck` directly in the remote repository or on a new clone? Only the former would give you meaningful results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

When you delete a branch (`git branch -d ...`), it removes the branch *name* (the pointer to the tip commit) and the branch's reflogs.  The commits themselves, however, stick around for a while, normally about three months, before being garbage-collected, as they're still referenced by one of the reflogs, the one for `HEAD`.

So, normally you would run `git log -g` (or use a graphical viewer that lets you look through the `HEAD` reflogs) and search for the last commit you made on `newbranch`.  For instance, you might see something like this:

```
commit e1189656a60f446de5b40137e8149f4bf5635986
Reflog: HEAD@{66} (You <your.name@your.email.addr>)
Reflog message: commit: Frobble the minifier
...
```

If that is the correct commit, then:

```
git branch newbranch e1189656a60f446de5b40137e8149f4bf5635986
```

will put the branch label back.

### Why that's no good here

You quote the last two commands above as:

```
cd ..
rm -rf myproject
```

This would remove the entire clone, including `myproject/.git` where git kept the repo objects and reflogs.

### So what options remain?

Perhaps there's a backup that was made at some point while the directory `myproject` existed.  Local backups of your local clone could have most or all of what you want to recover.

If not, well, you did this:

```
git clone ssh://.../myproject
...
git push
```

Let's give this machine (the target of the `ssh://`) a name, `O` for origin.

If all went well, the push copied the commits and their trees and files to `O` and set a branch label `newbranch` on `O`, pointing to the tip-most commit.  The later `push --delete` removed the branch label.  Unfortunately ... well:

Let's say you can log in to `O` and poke around in the `myproject` git repository there.  You might try to look in *their* reflogs (assuming they have any).  Alas, `git push --delete` would have removed the reflog for the branch `newbranch`, which is the only place the push itself was likely to be recorded.

Next, you can try running `git fsck` there and look for "dangling commit".  According to the comments above, though, you did this already and got nothing, which implies that git already did a garbage-collection pass and removed the commit objects and hence everything else you're looking for as well.

### The takeaway

(1) Backups are good.  Check for backups.

(2) Don't `rm -rf` your git repositories, if you can avoid it.

Comment: Oh my gosh I feel like someone I loved died and I can't realize that. when committing a password (for example) in a file and pushing, one needs to remove that commit. It is very painful because it seems git remembers everything. Well this doesn't happen to branches I guess. Sad to learn that and I guess it is a lesson for future development. 
<TLDR> Thanks for being clear in the explanation and telling me not to look around on the internet anymore because there is no other way / ghost command, this helps a lot

Comment: Git's "remember everything" relies on keeping the repo files (`.git/*`)....  You might check for backups done on machine `O` too.  The pushed-then-deleted branch's repo files probably hung around for a day or two, which might be long enough to have gotten backed-up.